# MacBook Pro tainted by Grub after using Ubuntu live usb

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, live-usb, macbook

Maybe someone can help me out with this:

So my MacBook Pro with Retina display (15-inch, Mid 2015) is having boot issues. I have a dual boot situation set up with macOS 10.13.3 and Windows 10 that I configured with Bootcamp, and I have an Ubuntu 17.10 live USB that I've been using off and on for the past few days

When I first set up the live USB drive and booted from it, I think it may have left traces of GNU Grub in it that may have overwritten Windows Boot Manager, because my macOS partition boots just fine from the option menu and by just pressing the power key and booting to the macOS partition which I've set up as the default, but when I try to boot into Windows it will display a message from Grub saying something about a broken boot order for a split second (I had to take a slo-mo video of it with my iPhone in order to even see what it said because it was on the screen so briefly).

I really need to access my Windows partition and I'm placing wiping the SSD as a last resort unless any of you bright people can point me in the direction of a solution. Thanks so much in advance for your help!!

Comment: Where it begin? Can you see the Windows partition form macOS? Can you post the output from the command `diskutil list`? Most likely you need to reinstall the Windows boot files, but I would like to see your answers to my questions before proceeding.

Comment: You problem is similar to this question: [Recover Bootcamp EFI Folder/fix boot entries?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/308729/recover-bootcamp-efi-folder-fix-boot-entries) I would need to know about your problem before I would recommend using the posted solution.